# Automatically call method after __init__ in child class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(f"init Parent")

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        print(f"init Child")

    def post_init(self):
        print(f"post init")

Child()
```

Here I get the output:

```
init Parent
init Child
```

Is it possible to modify the code **in the Parent-class** to call the post_init method from the Child-class automatically after the `___init___()` of the Parent **and** the Child-class. I would like to have the following output:

```
init Parent
init Child
post init
```

I don't want to modify the Child-class!!!
I have already tried to define a decorator in the Parent-class, but I failed.

EDIT:

The Parent-class is a pattern-class and is multiple used in multiple children. So I don't want to take care every time i use the Child-class. Is it possible on using the abstract-package?

Comment: Probably possible with metaclasses or perhaps something along the lines of the new `__init_subclass__`. But as most people here would ask, "why?" EDIT: I misinterpreted the question slightly due to the title, but explaining why would still be good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited the question to improve it. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `__init_subclass__` to override the `__init__`:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"init Parent")

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
        def new_init(self, *args, init=cls.__init__, **kwargs):
            init(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.post_init()
        cls.__init__ = new_init
```

---

#### Supporting grandchildren

To only call after a grandchild class's `__init__`, we need an additional check to see if the `__init__` being called is that of the grandchild's:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init Parent")

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
        def new_init(self, *args, init=cls.__init__, **kwargs):
            init(self, *args, **kwargs)
            if cls is type(self):
                self.post_init()
        cls.__init__ = new_init
```

Example usage:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("init Child")

    def post_init(self):
        print("post init")

class Grandchild(Child):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("init Grandchild")


_ = Grandchild()
```

Output:

```
init Parent
init Child
init Grandchild
post init
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. I have to test it later if it is the best for my need.

Comment: And then someone defines a *grandchild* class, and they get *two* `post_init` calls every time they instantiate the grandchild.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I suppose one could use a counter/flag to determine the distance from `Parent`... but then what would one do about situations where the grandchild is also a child of `Parent`? EDIT: Nevermind, the easiest thing would be to keep track of the number of `post_init`  calls.

Comment: Thank you for help. Including your last edit (Supporting grandchildren) it works as I want. But finally I must say it is a pity to have no built-in-function (e.g. __post_init__) to simply run a method after initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write code like this:

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance.post_init()
        return instance

class Parent(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print(f"init Parent")

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        print(f"init Child")

    def post_init(self):
        print(f"post init")

Child()
```

Comment: What if my Parent-class is also a child of an other class (e.g.: class Parent(QWidget, metaclass=Meta):). Now I get the error: ```TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases```

Comment: In such a case, `__init_subclass__` is the best choice.